# SQLite Database vs online database C# UWP

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp

I have an UWP project with SQLite database stored locally. The app is going to be used by multiple users and I am writing a Client app. Client app should pull data from users database.

Is there a way to achieve this without leaving SQLite behind?

I really like what I learned about how the SQLite works and would not like to just bin all the work I did.

Is it possible to do something like uploading users' data to the server and then retrieve it using client app?
Something like uploading the localDB file to the server and downloading it by client app would work? Or is it not a recommended workaround?

Ok, I learned that I can keep using SQLite as an offline database and then sync it over the net using my server and SQLiteSync framework. I will definitely go for it. But I have one more question:

How do I extract/mark data of each user from all the others? I mean, since the SQLite is offline and local db solution, I did not implement any user/password thing. Is there an easy way to do this afterwards?

Comment: `Is it possible to do something like uploading users' data to the server and then retrieve it using client app?` Yes. https://github.com/sqlite-sync/SQLite-sync.com

Comment: thanks for the link. going to readd it now.

Comment: Chances are that most of the knowledge you've gained isn't SQLite-specific - most database clients are ADO.NET implementations, which all work similarly. That doesn't mean you _have_ to step away from SQLite, of course, but perhaps it's good to know.

Comment: ok, I like the idea that I can keep SQLite offline and use SQL to exchange data between clients. But there is one more question from my part. How do I extract/mark data of each user from all the others?

Comment: That is a new question @positiveperspective. Please create a new one and we'd love to help.